# Ansible Jinja template with lists of dictionaries

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to make a template for the following yml to jinja template but the list inside the dict is not able to make it can someone help

```yaml
--- 
documentDB_secgroup: 
  description: " Document DB instance security group "
  name:  'aws_docuemntDB'
  rules: 
    - 
      cidr_ip: 
        - 1
        - 2
        - 3
      from_port: "{{ documentDB_port }}"
      proto: tcp
      to_port: "{{ documentDB_port }}"
    - 
      cidr_ip: "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"
      from_port: "{{ documentDB_port }}"
      proto: tcp
      to_port: "{{ documentDB_port }}"
```

values

```yaml
documentDB_subnet_group: "dev_documentDB"
documentDB_port: 27017
vpc_cidr_block: "10.0.0.0/16"
ip_addresses:
  buildslaves:
    - "10.0.5.29/32"
    - "10.0.5.30/32"
    - "10.0.5.31/32"
documentDB_env: "dev"
documentDB_secgroup:
  rules:
    - proto: tcp
      from_port: "{{ documentDB_port }}"
      to_port: "{{ documentDB_port }}"
      cidr_ip: 
         - "{{ ip_addresses['buildslaves'] }}"
```

expected result

```yaml
- IpProtocol: tcp
  FromPort: 27017
  ToPort: 27017
  cidr_ip:10.0.5.29/32          
- IpProtocol: tcp
  FromPort: 27017
  ToPort: 27017
  cidr_ip:10.0.5.30/32 
- IpProtocol: tcp
  FromPort: 27017
  ToPort: 27017
  cidr_ip:10.0.5.31/32 
- IpProtocol: tcp
  FromPort: 27017
  ToPort: 27017
  cidr_ip:110.0.0.0/16
```

tried like this

```
{% for rule in documentDB_secgroup.rules %}
{% for cidr in rule.cidr_ip %}
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: "{{ rule.from_port }}"
          ToPort: "{{ rule.to_port }}"
          CidrIp: "{{ cidr }}"
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

but its getting the list expanded for  - `"{{ ip_addresses['buildslaves'] }}"`

Comment: don't know  how to refer to get the list value from second loop for the list

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page,
and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section. You have a lot of words, and a lot of code snippets, but we have no idea what _problem_ you're facing. Labeling what files those code snippets belong to would be a great start, as would fleshing out the "but getting" section to contrast it with the "expected" section

Comment: What do you want to do with the list `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Can leave the [1,2,3] , it was similar with to the ips that i was adding it as a sample list., one of the list is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the simplified data

```yaml
documentDB_secgroup:
  rules: 
    - cidr_ip: [1, 2, 3]
    - cidr_ip: "{{ ip_addresses.buildslaves }}"
    - cidr_ip: "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"

vpc_cidr_block: 10.0.0.0/16
ip_addresses:
  buildslaves:
    - 10.0.5.29/32
    - 10.0.5.30/32
    - 10.0.5.31/32
```

The expected result should be

```yaml
- cidr_ip: 10.0.5.29/32          
- cidr_ip: 10.0.5.30/32 
- cidr_ip: 10.0.5.31/32 
- cidr_ip: 110.0.0.0/16
```

[Test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests) the type of the value in the template

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for rule in documentDB_secgroup.rules %}
          {% if rule.cidr_ip is string %}
          - CidrIp: {{ rule.cidr_ip }}
          {% elif rule.cidr_ip is iterable %}
          {% for ip in rule.cidr_ip %}
          - CidrIp: {{ ip }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    - CidrIp: 1
    - CidrIp: 2
    - CidrIp: 3
    - CidrIp: 10.0.5.29/32
    - CidrIp: 10.0.5.30/32
    - CidrIp: 10.0.5.31/32
    - CidrIp: 10.0.0.0/16
```

This leaves the open question: What do you want to do with the list `[1, 2, 3]`?

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    documentDB_secgroup:
      rules: 
        - cidr_ip: [1, 2, 3]
        - cidr_ip: "{{ ip_addresses.buildslaves }}"
        - cidr_ip: "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"

    vpc_cidr_block: 10.0.0.0/16
    ip_addresses:
      buildslaves:
        - 10.0.5.29/32
        - 10.0.5.30/32
        - 10.0.5.31/32

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for rule in documentDB_secgroup.rules %}
          {% if rule.cidr_ip is string %}
          - CidrIp: {{ rule.cidr_ip }}
          {% elif rule.cidr_ip is iterable %}
          {% for ip in rule.cidr_ip %}
          - CidrIp: {{ ip }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the solution. it works need to encapsulate this to the AWS cloudformation for EC2 Secgroup creation